# Android: is it possible to create the database in to PC and then use that database by integrating it in to android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-design, android-ndk

I don't want to create the database at runtime.
That's why I use the database manager to create the database from pc.
Now I want to add this database into My android application. And then I want to use that data from the database.

I know that we can access the file that we have put into the assets directory of the project. But is it is possible to do the same thing for the database? And after doing that can we able to access the data?

So is it possible? If yes then how?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use adb push on the command line or DDMS import/export via eclispe to put the db on to your emulator

[Here](http://www.boringmonday.com/jc/2010/11/22/sqlite-database-on-your-android-emulator/) is a more details step by step

Comment: I dont want to push the db file in to project. i want to add it in to assets folder and then want to use it from the application. So is it possible ?

Comment: both are same thing, only folder path & name is difference.